# Wrapping a CustomScrollView and a Sliverlist with a Streambuilder throws exception

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder, flutter-sliver, customscrollview

I am trying to listen for real-time documents from Firebase firestore using `Streambuilder` while displaying the retrieved data in a `CustomScrollView` and a `SliverList`but when I do so the list breaks and the screen remains blank.

I tried a `FutureBuilder` and it worked, but it doesn't satisfy my requirements.

This is the code I wrote for the streambuilder:

```
Widget sliverList() {
  return CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        expandedHeight: 220.0,
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          collapseMode: CollapseMode.parallax,
          background: Column(
            children: [Daily(), AddPost()],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: feedServices.listenToFeedinStream(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            return SliverFixedExtentList(
              itemExtent: 500,
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    Post post = Post.fromMap(snapshot.data.docs[index].data());
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        FeedItem(
                          thread: post,
                        ),
                        seperator()
                      ],
                    );
                  } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Text('no data');
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text('has err');
                  } else {
                    return Text('not specified');
                  }
                },
                childCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
              ),
            );
          })
    ],
  );
}
```

Exceptions caught:

```
flutter: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(dirty, state:
flutter: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>>#da6d3):
flutter: The getter 'docs' was called on null.
flutter: Receiver: null
flutter: Tried calling: docs
```

Comment: Please provide the exception message.

Comment: @hacker1024 consider reviewing the updated question, I added the exception caught

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only pass Sliver Widgets to `slivers` list.
`StreamBuilder` isn't a Sliver, so you can wrap whole `CustomScrollView` with `StreamBuilder`.

```
Widget sliverList() {
  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: feedServices.listenToFeedinStream(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            expandedHeight: 220.0,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              collapseMode: CollapseMode.parallax,
              background: Column(
                children: [Daily(), AddPost()],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverFixedExtentList(
              itemExtent: 500,
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    Post post = Post.fromMap(snapshot.data.docs[index].data());
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        FeedItem(
                          thread: post,
                        ),
                        seperator()
                      ],
                    );
                  } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Text('no data');
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text('has err');
                  } else {
                    return Text('not specified');
                  }
                },
                childCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
              ),
            )
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: that solved it, I had to wrap `CustomScrollView` with an `Expanded`.